# Uploading multiple dependent android libraries to maven central

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have following project structure in android studio

```
root project
    - libA
    - libB
    - libCommon
    - library (empty - just depends on libA, libB, libC)
```

where all are android library projects and both libA and libB are dependent on libCommon.
Now I am trying to push the entire project to maven central using Sonatype for which i am following this code https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push

The problem is that only one project is getting uploaded to the Sonatype repo which is happens to be the last one - library blank with no dependencies added.

How can i upload entire project ?

Comment: What command are you executing and from what directory?